# % Change to Prior Column

Tags: looker

So I have a series of data that the EU would like visualized as a bar chart displaying the % variance to the prior month. They only want the last 4 months. Easy enough. My problem is being a perfectionist I'd like the 4 months displayed BUT you technically need 5 months of data pulled to get 4 months of data and the 5th month has no value displayed because there's nothing to compare it to. Filters of course drop the 5th month's value. I just want it to not show that fifth month.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem:

- Use the `Limit Displayed Rows` option in the Visualization Settings:

  [image: Limit Displayed Rows options is at the bottom of the 'plot' tab of the Visualisation Settings.]

  Choose to `Hide the First 1 rows` with the data of the 5th month being the first row to hide it. Source: [Looker docs](https://docs.looker.com/exploring-data/visualizing-query-results/table-next-options#:%7E:text=switch%20to%20rows.-,Limit%20Displayed%20Rows,-Limit%20Displayed%20Rows)
- Create a custom calculation to exclude that specific row. The calculation should be something like `diff_months(${data.created_month},now())!=5`. The value should be `Yes` except for the month you want to exclude. Then click on the Settings wheel next to your calculation's name and select `Hide "No"'s from Visualization` and `Hide from Visualization`.

Romain